# How to use numpy array divide?

Tags: numpy

```
In [2]: x = np.array([5,4,3,2])

In [3]: y = np.array([2,2,2,2])
```

Both are int format and when I use `x/y`, the output are floor int of every element.
How to divide each element and get the float result. For example : `2.5, 2, 1.5, 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.true_divide`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html) -

```
np.true_divide(x,y)
```

Sample run -

```
In [53]: x = np.array([5,4,3,2])

In [54]: y = np.array([2,2,2,2])

In [55]: np.true_divide(x,y)
Out[55]: array([ 2.5,  2. ,  1.5,  1. ])
```

Alternatively, you can also use `from __future__ import division`, but this will keep the divisions as floating one for the rest of the session -

```
In [56]: x/y
Out[56]: array([2, 2, 1, 1])

In [57]: from __future__ import division

In [58]: x/y
Out[58]: array([ 2.5,  2. ,  1.5,  1. ])
```